# ambiguous column name при создании VIEW в котором два поля ссылаются на одну и ту же таблицу

Tags: sqlite3

Есть таблица сотрудников в которой есть поле fio. Текстовое. Есть результирующая таблица в которой есть поля sender_id и reciever_id. Оба целочисленые. При попытке создать View

```
CREATE VIEW "problem_list_view" AS 
select problem_list.id,
        problem_list.date_start,
        users.fio as fio_sender,
        problem_list.problem_text,
        problem_list.solution_text,
        users.fio as fio_reciever,
        problem_list.date_end,
        statuses.name as status
from problem_list
left JOIN users on problem_list.sender_id = users.id
left join users on problem_list.receiever_id = users.id
left join statuses on problem_list.status_id = statuses.id
```

Получаю ошибку ambiguous column name: И это мне понятно, sql говорит о неоднозначности
Я добавил в результирующую таблицу два поля fio_s и fio_r, ну чтобы различие было.

```
CREATE VIEW "problem_list_view" AS 
select problem_list.id,
        problem_list.date_start,
        users.fio_s as fio_sender,
        problem_list.problem_text,
        problem_list.solution_text,
        users.fio_r as fio_reciever,
        problem_list.date_end,
        statuses.name as status
from problem_list
left JOIN users on problem_list.sender_id = users.id
left join users on problem_list.receiever_id = users.id
left join statuses on problem_list.status_id = statuses.id
```

Но получил ту же ошибку. Вот теперь мне непонятно. Поля то разные. Подскажите где я ошибся, и как такую проблему решить правильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте алиасы для таблиц сейчас у вас в запросе две сущности с именем `users`, само собой движок не знает, к какому именно `users` вы обращаетесь в запросе и в джойнах

```
CREATE VIEW "problem_list_view" AS 
select problem_list.id,
        problem_list.date_start,
        sender.fio_s as fio_sender,
        problem_list.problem_text,
        problem_list.solution_text,
        receiver.fio_r as fio_reciever,
        problem_list.date_end,
        statuses.name as status
from problem_list
left JOIN users as sender on problem_list.sender_id = sender.id
left join users as receiver on problem_list.receiever_id = receiver.id
left join statuses on problem_list.status_id = statuses.id
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. Все теперь понятно. Тема закрыта

Comment: @ia_prosto_coder если ответ вас устраивает - отметьте его как верный